# How can I replace a string with html using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, regex, string, parsing

I am having trouble figuring out how to add elements to an HTML string. I tried using .nextUntil() and then I realized I can not target specific characters with that, only elements. I then looked into parsing and regex, but I'm still not grasping how to achieve the following. I have a variable 'itemOptions' that needs to be converted to html.

**Original:**

`itemOptions = '*First Item|2000*Second Item|1500*Third Item|700';`

**What I Need:**

```
itemOptions = '<li>First Item - <span>$2000</span></li><li>Second Item - <span>$1500</span></li><li>Third Item - <span>$700</span></li>';
$('ul.item-options').html(itemOptions );
```

I'd appreciate an explanation on how you converted it. Thank you!

Comment: Solve what? what is the problem ? Incomplete question.

Comment: Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. Make an attempt to do the work, and *if* you run into a specific problem doing so, post your code and ask about that specific problem.

Comment: ClasG was able to help me with his answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a regex like

```
/\*([^|*]+)\|([^|*]+)(?=\*|$)/g
```

and substitute with

```
<li>$1<span>$2</span></li>
```

should do it.

It matches the initial asterisk, captures everything up to a `|` into group 1. Matches the `|` and captures the rest into group 2, up to another asterisk, or end of line using a positive look-ahead.

```js
itemOptions = '*First Item|2000*Second Item|1500*Third Item|700';

itemOptions = itemOptions.replace(/\*([^|*]+)\|([^|*]+)(?=\*|$)/g, function(a,b,c) {
  return '<li>' + b + ' <span style="color:red">' + c + '</span></li>';
});

document.write(itemOptions);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for but I wasn't sure how to ask or search for it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Can also do it using [split()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) and [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) with jQuery

```js
var itemOptions = '*First Item|2000*Second Item|1500*Third Item|700';

// first, you make an array with split() from var using "*" as delimiter
var explItemOptions = itemOptions.split("*");

// you loop on that array
$(explItemOptions).each(function(index, value) {
  // check if the value exist
  if (value !== "") {
    // now you split the value using "|" as delimiter
    var OptionsValues = value.split("|");
  
    // formating the result
    $("body").append('<li>' + OptionsValues[0] + ' - <span style="color:red">$' + OptionsValues[1] + '</span></li>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```